# Azure Media Services v3 : Indexing after encoding with adaptivestreaming

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to index (with AudioAnalyzerPreset) and caption a video with Azure Media Services v3, after encoding with "AdaptiveStreaming" preset (recommended by Azure).
But, it is not generating any .vtt file etc

Does Azure Media Services v3 support indexing of video files encoded with "AdaptiveStreaming"? What about captions? Is this supported at all?

Answer (score 0):

> What about captions?

It seems that it is **not supported** currently. I find a similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/1710506f-6adc-4679-8d21-c4663ce352fc/azure-media-services-v3-preset-for-generating-captions-azure-media-indexer-2-preview).

> At this time, there is not a supported method to use Azure Media Indexer within AMS v3. This feature is still in preview state within v2,